# How can I save data in ReactiveX

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex, rx-py

I'm new to ReactiveX and I have a question. How can I save data in ReactiveX. For example. I have this code.

```
last_price = market_data_service.get_last_price("IBM")
difference = previous_last_price - last_price
```

For its correct work, I need to know the previous value of the price. How can I save the previous price in ReactiveX.

Comment: What does it mean "save data"? Rx has some operators, that collects previous emisions(collect, scan). Are you sure, that reactive streams suitable for your task?

Answer (score 0):

In RX methods returns `Observable<T>`. So in your case, above should be:

```
int previous_last_price = 10;
Single<Integer> market_data_service = Single.just(5);
Single<Integer> difference = market_data_service.map(last_price -> previous_last_price - last_price);
```